# Chrome loading tabs?

Tags: google-chrome

for the past several months (or over a year) I've had many tabs open up in chrome. I know they can't be stopped from loading, but what I've been doing is disconnecting my computer from the internet, bringing up Chrome, letting the pages load to the "Cannot connect to the internet" page, re-connecting to the internet and continuing on. Which worked fantastically (As id just load them up when I needed them) until last night (Sept. 10th, 2014). Now, when I re-connect to the internet AFTER all my tabs have gone to "Cannot connect to the internet", it starts reloading my tabs all over again as if I had just opened Chrome. Is there any way to change it back? Or revert back to an older version of chrome.

Comment: What is it about these other tabs that concerns you? Why don't you just close them?

Comment: There are things such as shows and such. But a few are for work, and others that I don't want to lose them. I change the tabs as well (referencing manuals, online references, and such), and closing the tabs then having to re-open them later via history or other means takes up too much time.

Comment: And pulling out your network cable and waiting doesn't take time? Bookmarks are your friend.

Comment: This seems to be asking how to make Chrome not work.  Instead of trying to break it, use bookmarks and let Chrome work as it is supposed to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Google Chrome's Auto-update feature?](http://superuser.com/questions/533750/how-to-disable-google-chromes-auto-update-feature)

Comment: Is using an alternative browser an option?  Firefox works the way you want by default.  It can be set to remembers previously open tabs and then, when you close and reopen it, it will only go to the network for the page contents when you actually click on the tab.  It has the other benefit of looking almost exactly like Chrome since the UI update a short while back.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a direct solution to the question, but I've used an extension in the past.

### [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

It helps in suspending tabs, which is useful whether you don't want to load tabs and/or don't want tabs to hog on memory when not in use.