# Turn off Chrome updates

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to turn off Chrome's autoupdate feature? I'm trying to turn it off because I'm currently on a metered connection.

I tried to set the value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update\UpdateDefault` to `0`, but that didn't help.

Comment: related http://superuser.com/questions/533750/how-to-disable-google-chromes-auto-update-feature

Answer (score 6):

#### Is there a way to turn off Chrome's auto-update feature?

There are 3 possible solutions:

1. Disable Chrome Update scheduled tasks.
2. Disable "Google Update" plugin.
3. Modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update`

---

#### Solution 1 - Disable Chrome Update scheduled tasks

1. "Start" > "Run" > "Task Scheduler"
2. Select "Task Scheduler Library"
3. Select "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore", right click and select "Disable"
4. Select "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA", right click and select "Disable"

   [image]
5. Close "Task Scheduler"

---

#### Solution 2 - Disable "Google Update" plugin

> 1. Enter "about: plugins" in the Address bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    [image]
> 2. Search for "Google Update" in the pop-up list and disable it.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Restart Chrome.

---

#### Solution 3 - Modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update`

> 1. Go the Registry Editor.
>
>    a. Windows 7 - press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the same time
>      to get the Run box, enter "regedit" press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
>    b. Windows 8 - move your cursor to the right corner of the top screen
>      to get the Charms bar. Then click on "Apps", enter "run" in the search
>      box, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>,  enter "regedit" in the pop-up box and
>      press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>
>    [image]
> 2. Navigate to the following key:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Update
>
>    [image]
> 3. Look for "UpdateDefault" on the right side of the Registry Editor and double click on it.
>
>    [image]
>
>    Note:
>
>    If you cannot find "UpdateDefault", right click on a blank place
>      in the right side > click "New" > "String Value" > Name it
>      "UpdateDefault"
> 4. Change the value data to `0`
>
>    [image]
> 5. Click "OK" to save the changes

Source [How to Stop Google Chrome from Automatic Update](http://blog.doofix.com/how-to-stop-google-chrome-from-automatic-update/)

Comment: The plugin isn't there, and changing the registry didn't work :(

Comment: @Erman According to https://support.google.com/installer/answer/146164?hl=en that should work :(

Comment: @DavidPostill - I can confirm the plugin does not exist.  Since I am using a portable version of Chrome that might have something to do with it.  The registry solution work, but that requires being an Administrator on the machine, and having a version of Windows with the group policy editor.

Comment: My version of windows doesn't seem to have the group policy editor

Comment: @Erman You can get the group policy from http://www.askvg.com/how-to-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-7-home-premium-home-basic-and-starter-editions/. I'm using it here on Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: There are 2 tasks for google updates in Task Scheduler that can be disabled to kill updates to chrome.

Comment: @moab. Good catch. I will add to my answer.

Comment: Good ol task scheduler, you can disable windows telemetry in there also, a bit more complicated as there are several tasks in different folders.

Comment: I can't get the Administrative Template from to https://support.google.com/installer/answer/146164?hl=enload into GPE :/

Comment: @Erman Another solution added as per comment from Moab.

Answer (score 2):

I found another and entirely different way to disable google chrome update in latest version 50.x. I followed this link [Halting auto-updates (Not Recommended)](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036?hl=en&rd=1)

1. You should get the Administrative template for your Windows, from [this link](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6350036?hl=en&rd=1#Obtaining_the_Administrative_Tem) mentioned in the article above.
2. Launch group policy editor `Navigate to Start > Run: gpedit.msc`
3. Import the template in this Administrative Templates screen,

   [image: google_policy_update]
4. Navigate to `Administrative Templates > Google > Google Update > Preferences`.
5. On the right side select `Modify the Auto-update check period override` and select edit `policy setting`
6. Enable this property and select the checkbox `Disable all the auto-update checks` below the "Minutes between update checks"

I did this in Windows 10 running Chrome version 50.0.2661.102 m.

Comment: +1, this looks like the official way to disable the updates.

Comment: GPO is not available in Windows 10 Home. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit GoogleUpdate.exe's NTFS permissions by, first, removing the inheritance:

```
icacls %localappdata%\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /inheritance:r
```

Then, remove the user's permissions to which the scheduled tasks "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore" and "GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA" are ran with:

```
icacls %localappdata%\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe /remove:g %userdomain%\%username%
```

Depending on your Google Chrome Installation, the path may be different. I suggest taking a look in the "Action" tab of both scheduled tasks to extract the exact path.

EDIT: Actually, this feels like it's not enough. The GoogleUpdate.exe might not be there when you install Chrome and could be added later. You might want to create an empty file Chrome won't be able to overwrite:

```
mkdir %localappdata%\Google\Update\
copy NUL %localappdata%\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with 2 simple steps:

1. Go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\`
2. Rename `Update` folder (for ex to `Update.bak`)

That's it.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Dear down voter, could you please explain the reason of your vote? I tested this solution and it works!