# How did Google Chrome just update itself when I had forcefully disabled updates and removed Google Update?

Tags: google-chrome, security, updates

Here's the deal -- I *just didn't* want my Chrome installation to update, for certain reasons that are irrelevant here:

- I'd disabled Google Update in the Group Policy (yes, I know Chrome ignores it)
- I'd disabled the Google Update services
- I'd uninstalled Google Update (not that Google was honest enough to make this work, but still)
- I'd even **removed** the Google Update program files in `C:\Program Files` manually

#### ...and this *was working* for many weeks... *until yesterday*!

Until yesterday, Chrome kept nagging me with its usual Chrome-is-out-of-date and Chrome-is-broken-please-reinstall popups.  And if I tried to manually update Chrome, it failed -- it gave error 0x80040154. So I knew I was doing something right (or wrong, depending on your point of view).

But today morning I woke up only to find that Chrome had magically updated itself, which drove me very angry and confused at Google. So in one sentence, here's my question:

#### How did Google force-push an update to my Chrome despite my actions?

Some follow-up questions that are on my mind right now:

Is this in the Chromium source code somewhere, or is it a Google Chrome-specific feature?
Is this a well-known capability? Has it ever been publicized before? Has Google acknowledged it?
From my perspective it seems quite dishonest to "backdoor" this so slyly, and I didn't know they would.
Heck, is someone at Google monitoring my installation or something?

Comment: Hey, they nagged and nagged and you didn't listen.  They finally had to go ahead and do it for you so you wouldn't complain about not having the latest features or having some vulnerability.  What are you, some kind of ingrate?  :-)

Comment: "Heck, is someone at Google monitoring my installation or something?" -- If you mean "are they gathering tons of metrics from your browser, including version",  the answer is absolutely yes.

Comment: @XiongChiamiov: No, I meant more like going out of their way to push updates to my system in an abnormal way.