# Prevent Google Chrome From Auto Updating

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome

Before any mods go and mark this as a duplicate, I read [Disable auto-update of Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/272205/disable-auto-update-of-google-chrome) and I read [How to disable Google Chrome's Auto-update feature?](https://superuser.com/questions/533750/how-to-disable-google-chromes-auto-update-feature).

The problem is that none of these methods prevent Chrome 46 running on Windows XP SP3 from auto updating. As far as the GPO method everything looks as if it will work, however if I open Chrome and close it a few minutes later and then reopen it and its running version 49.  I would like to keep it from going to Chrome 49.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Google Chrome's Auto-update feature?](http://superuser.com/questions/533750/how-to-disable-google-chromes-auto-update-feature)

Comment: @Ramhound I tried the GPO method as listed in the answer suggested but it doesn't seem to prevent it on Windows XP.

Comment: Worked in my testing